# Cannot create an instance of an abstract class Random in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In get Number method. when I use Random() method android studio give me error message Cannot create an instance of an abstract class please tell me how to solve this error.

```
class MainActivityDataGenerator : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var myRandomNumber : String

    fun getNumber(): String{
        Log.i(Tag, "Get Number")
        if (!::myRandomNumber.isInitialized){
            this.createNumber()
        }
        return myRandomNumber
    }

    fun createNumber(){
        Log.i(Tag, "create new Number")
        val  random = Random()

        myRandomNumber = " Number "+ (random.nextInt(10-1)+1)

    }

    companion object{
       private val  Tag : String = MainActivityDataGenerator::class.java.simpleName
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's the difference in import statement.

If you want to use the Kotlin Random class then use like this. with below import.

```
import kotlin.random.Random
//.....

   val random = Random(12)
```

if you want to use the Java one which you seems to then use it like this.

```
import java.util.*
//.....

    val random = Random()
```

just remove the kotlin one or add the seed value in constructor it will work.

Comment: Don't actually use `Random(12)` unless you want to get the same random values on each run of your program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a seed number to Random class to create an object. Here I modified your code and explained everything inside code with comments.

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlin.random.Random

class MainActivityDataGenerator : ViewModel() {
    private lateinit var myRandomNumber : String

    fun getNumber(): String{
        Log.i(Tag, "Get Number")
        if (!::myRandomNumber.isInitialized){
            this.createNumber()
        }
        return myRandomNumber
    }

    fun createNumber(){
        Log.i(Tag, "create new Number")

        /* Initialize it with a seed number. Seed is used to generate a random
        number sequence. Two different Object of Random class with same seed number will
        generate same sequences of random number. If you want different sequences
        use different seed numbers to different objects*/

        val  random = Random(10)

        myRandomNumber = " Number "+ (random.nextInt(10-1)+1)

    }

    companion object{
        private val  Tag : String = MainActivityDataGenerator::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```