# Is there a way to remove this 'cannot create instance of abstract class'?

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my MainActivity.kt code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val rollButton : Button= findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
    rollButton.setOnClickListener {
        rollDice()
    }
}

private fun rollDice() {
    val resultText: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text)

    val randomInt = Random().nextInt(6) + 1

    resultText.text = randomInt.toString()
}
}
```

In this code, this is the error

```
Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
```

This error is for `Random()` I also imported `import kotlin.random.Random`
If someone could please help me?

Comment: Will this be helpful ? val randomInt = (1..6).random()

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin random is

```
Random
```

So `Random.nextInt()` will fix it.

If you go to the import and then click `ctrl+b` or `cmd+b` it will take you to the `Random` file. Scroll down and you will find the companion object, there all of the methods are exposed for simplicity. So you are basically saying `Random file dot use the companion object method nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60124584/10012330 <-- check here

If you want to use the Kotlin Random class then use like this. with below import.

```
import kotlin.random.Random

val random = Random(12)
```

Comment: @cutiko's answer is the better approach. There are cases where you want to set a seed explicitly but not usually to a constant value.